# Convert a list of stream values to a stream of values with fs2

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2, cats-effect

I would like to define a function with the following signature using [fs2](https://fs2.io/) Streams, cats [EitherT](https://typelevel.org/cats/) and [cats-effect](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/) IO.

```
def list2Stream[A,B,F[_],S](vs: List[A], 
                             f: A => EitherT[IO,S,Stream[IO,B]]
                             ): EitherT[IO,S,Stream[IO,B]] = {
   ???
}
```

which would map each value from vs to a stream of values and collect all those values in a new stream.

I tried something like:

```
  vs.map(f).sequence.flatten
```

but it seems there is no implicit definition for Stream.

Answer (score 2):

The following answer was provided in the gitter channel by Michael Pilquist:

```
 vs.traverse(f).map(s => Stream.emits(s).flatten)
```